# SQL String Split

Tags: sql, t-sql, split

After some advice, I currently have a string of data stored within a nvarchar field called response_string in SQL, I want to only get out the wording between `<tag>` and `</tag>`
e.g. `<tag>test</tag>` this would return `test`.

I am currently using the code below but it just seems overly complicated to me and I wanting to know if there was a better way of writing it.

```
(case when charindex('</tag>',[response_String])>charindex('<tag>',[response_String]) 
then substring([response_String],charindex('<tag>',[response_String])+(11),(charindex('</tag>',[response_String])-charindex('<tag>',[response_String]))-(11))  end)
```

Unfortunately due to the way I am having to use this code I cannot use a function.

Comment: Provide the sample string

Comment: Hi John, my example did originally contain an example but seems to have been extracted the string would be `<tag>test</tag>`

Comment: Is that an XML?

Comment: It was but is being stored as an nvarchar(max) and sometimes the data inside isn't exactly properly formatted XML

Comment: If the XML is malformed can we avoid extracting the value in that case?

Comment: Unfortunately not, the user wants the value even if the xml is malformed, I think I will be asked at some point to flag which ones these are.

Comment: @PJD garbage in garbage out.  Fix the problem on how malformed xml tags are being entered and use dudumarkovitz's answer.

Comment: xQbert, I totally agree but I am afraid that I have no control over how the xml is generated, this is put together by an external source and unfortunately I am left with the fallout.

Comment: Any reason why you can't use a split/parse UDF?

Comment: please update your question with the comments you added about not using a function call and other

Answer (score 0):

```
select try_cast('<tag>test</tag>' as xml).value('/tag[1]','nvarchar(100)')
```

Comment: Wouldn't the cast raise an error if the string is not a well formatted xml?

Comment: I had tried going down this route before but due to the badly formatted xml sometimes I was ending up with 2 many errors, the other option would be to correct the format of the XML but again this seemed to be adding more complexity.

Comment: @PJD, I would like to give it a shot. Can we identify a pattern in the way the XML is malformed?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the select query where this column with **tag** is appearing as below. It will not raise the error, if  is missing.

`select   replace( replace(column_name ,  "<tag>","" ),  "</tag>","")    from   table_name`

If there are max 2-3 nodes, can use as above, but in case many than considering the way data is stored.. 3-4 sets of replace may make query bit awkward, to deal with a view can be created..

Comment: Hi Girish,  I looked at your suggestion and it worked fine up until it found that sometimes the tag brackets are wrapped in a further node of `<level></level>` which I wasn't expecting in the first place, I am thinking that were there might be one extra node there could be more going forward.

Comment: Hi - I have updated my comments in answer..however handling them in database, will much faster than handling them in java..